# Using QtCreator 5.3 for Qt Quick UI project, how to link QML button resource to C++ function call

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

This is my first post on StackOverflow so please excuse any formatting mistakes I might have made.

I'm building a Qt Quick UI project using Qt Quick Controls 1.1 and I have a simple Button in my QML code that I would like to call into my C++ action class. I see a number of examples on this with earlier versions of Qt, but they do not seem to work in 5.3. I chose Qt Quick Controls 1.1 in the project settings. I know this must not be too complicated to do, but I can't seem to find examples using QtCreator 5.3

Here is my main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: parentWnd
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Action {
        id: actionSend
        onTriggered: console.log("SEND")
    }

    Button {
        id: send
        text: "Send Request"
        action: actionSend
        signal sendSignal()
    }
}
```

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the action class where I would like the QML button to call "doSend":

```
#include<QDebug>
#include<QObject>

class Action : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Action();
public slots:
    void doSend();
};
```

Finally here is my project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    action.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    action.h
```

When I run this, I see the button and I see the logging of "SEND" to the console so I know the QML Action is setup correctly. Any help on how to make the Action call into my action class would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues that you're running into here.

The first is that you haven't [registered](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#registering-c-types-with-the-qml-type-system) your `Action` class with QML in `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Action>("StevesModule", 1, 0, "Action");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

The second is that [Action](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-action.html#details) is a QML type in the Qt Quick Controls module. It doesn't know anything about your `Action` class in C++. If you want to use your `Action` class instead of Qt Quick Controls' `Action` type, you must import it in your QML file:

```
import StevesModule 1.0
```

The third is that you're not calling the `doSend()` slot anywhere. You can do this in the [onClicked handler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html#clicked-signal) of Button:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import StevesModule 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: parentWnd
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Action {
        id: actionSend
    }

    Button {
        id: send
        text: "Send Request"
        onClicked: actionSend.doSend()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I actually just found an easier way to do what I need that I'll explain in a response. I'm voting you up because your solution is also valid and I learned from it. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently I have to just add a comment. Here's what I did which works as well. I found another way to accomplish the same thing is to make the C++ class available to the app's engine root context like so:

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("MyAction", new Action());
Then in the qml file I can do:

Action {
    id: actionSend
    onTriggered: MyObject.doSend()
}

Comment: Sorry, Mitch, I apparently don't have enough reputation points to vote you up.

Comment: No worries. :) The `setContextProperty` approach is good when you have a single object, and the `qmlRegisterType` approach is good for when you'd like to instantiate many items from within QML.